# Capturing un-encrypted HTTPS traffic using wireshark

Tags: http, https, wireshark

I am trying to capture HTTPS traffic between a client (windows machine) and a server. I would like to do this before the traffic is encrypted as I would like to analysis its contents.

Is there an easy way to do this on the local machine? For example, could I set up a local HTTP proxy to achieve this?

Comment: Did my answer http://serverfault.com/a/730386/101203 solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you upvote and/or mark it as accepted so I get credit and also so people in the future who read this know that it was a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up a proxy like Fiddler to do this.

After you install and launch it, you have to enable HTTPS decryption in its options.